# Bug in GNOME's Java-Atk-Wrapper - how to disable accessibility for a Swing component or application?

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, gnome

I believe I found a bug in the Java wrapper for GNOME Accessibility, resulting in a critical performance problem in my Scala/Java applications that use Tree or Table UI.

- [bug](https://github.com/GNOME/java-atk-wrapper/blob/2d362dbcc8df35d8c0d16534f57eeaee055c2b66/wrapper/org/GNOME/Accessibility/AtkWrapper.java.in#L309)
- [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791970)

I need to avoid that `AtkWrapper` is listening to my tables and trees. How can I remove the Java Atk Wrapper from my system, or disable it from particular components of my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable GNOME accessibility globally, one can use this system property:

```
-Djavax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=
```

Comment: Note that this fails in OpenJDK 10: `java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: ` from `java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)`

Comment: Seems to suffice to comment out the one line `assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/accessibility.properties` after installing `openjdk-11-jdk` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to add that commenting the line worked better for me (trying to set an empty value just returned an error). Also the property file was under ~/jre/lib.

Comment: Thanks to the OP's diagnosis and bug report, the fix is available for installation on Debian Stretch, which they were running, with `sudo aptitude install libatk-wrapper-java-jni/stretch-backports`.