# OpenJDK 11.0.4 has java-atk-wrapper.jar in the classpath

Tags: java, openjdk-11

I noticed this issue when attempting to load the MANIFEST.MF from the .jar file of my application via `class.getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`.

Instead of getting my own manifest, a manifest is seemingly loaded from `/usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar`. 
However, this jar is not specified as part of my application's classpath - I tried disabling the java accessibility assistive technologies ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985068/bug-in-gnomes-java-atk-wrapper-how-to-disable-accessibility-for-a-swing-compo)), but this had no effect.

Interestingly, this behavior is specific to OpenJDK-11.0.4. The issue does not occur when using 11.0.3.
Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening here? Was there some kind of change to how java-internal jars/classes are loaded/accessed? Or could this simply be a bug introduced in 11.0.4?

**Minimal working example:**

```
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        System.out.println(resource.getPath());
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-116.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-116.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
file:/usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
$ echo $CLASSPATH

$
```

The *expexted* behavior of this code snippet would be to throw a NPE, because there is no manifest resource. Instead, the manifest is loaded from the atk-wrapper.

**Environment details:**

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

OpenJDK was freshly installed via apt

```
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

The apk-wrapper was *not* installed explicitly. I wasn't aware of its existence until this issue occurred on one of our machines - at which point I was able to reproduce it on my local machine as well.

Comment: What Linux distro are you using?  What version?  How did you install OpenJDK Java 11?  How did you install the Java ATK?  What is your CLASSPATH variable set to?

Comment: Right, sorry. Clarified in my post - ubuntu 16.04.5, openjdk11 was intalled via apt. The CLASSPATH environment variable actually isn't set at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce this with OpenJDK Java 11.0.4 on Fedora 29, I got a NPE.

```
$ javac Main.java 
$ java Main 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode, sharing)
$ echo $CLASSPATH

$
```

Then I tried to find `java-atk-wrapper.jar`.  Not there.  So I installed it via the package manager, and then ran your program again.

Still an NPE<sup>1</sup>.

Hmmm.

Conclusion: there is something weird about the OpenJDK Java 11.0.4 you have installed, but is NOT a bug in OpenJDK itself.

Note that the following OpenJDK bug report is relevant to this:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8204862

It seems to be saying that the OpenJDK team doesn't support / maintain the stuff inside that JAR file.

---

**UPDATE**

Given the extra information that you added to question, the problem would appear to be a bug in the OpenJDK packages for Debian / Ubuntu.  I found this Debian bug that seems to be related:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900912

I suspect that their attempts to fix the original bug ("Accessibility does not get loaded") has introduced this regression.

My advice to you would be:

1. Raise a new issue with Ubuntu / Debian.  Let them decide if this needs to be raised upstream, or whether it is their problem to fix.
2. If you want to try a hacky workaround, see what happens if you rename `java-atk-wrapper.jar` so that the launcher cannot find it.  It *might* work.
3. Alternatively (less hacky), see what Ubuntu package the JAR file comes from *on your system*.  If it makes sense, uninstall that package and whatever depends on it.

---

<sup>1 - The NPE happens because `getResource` is returning `null` ... because the class loader cannot find a manifest resource.  That's what *should* happen.</sup>

Comment: Right, the NPE is the expected behavior I'm getting in older versions of OpenJDK, but not with 11.0.4.

Thanks for the link, although it doesn't seem particularly helpful in this case - my issue isn't that the atk-wrapper fails to load, rather that it is too invasive in the way that it is loaded.

Comment: @RobinFood - well yes, but you understand my problem here.  You didn't provide the information needed to take the investigation further.

Comment: #3 actually provided a solution - thank you!
The openjdk-11-jdk package also installs the libatk-wrapper-java (which is the source of the jar-file). After removing libatk-wrapper-java, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me: 
Instead of deleting the libatk-wrapper-java , i iterated over all URL's from getResource**s** and chose the URL with the jar-name. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-

```
Env: 
$uname -a 
Linux hostname 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```